# Listing docker image in reverse chronological order using Artifactory API

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry

I am trying to use the below API to get the list of docker images so that I could populate the dropdown on Jenkins build. Is there a way that this could be listed in a reverse chronological order rather than alphanumerical so that the newest image is at the top ? Thanks.

/artifactory/api/docker/repo/v2/image/tags/list

Comment: looking for something similar... @aithusa did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to take help of Artifactory AQL query language.
An example AQL fragment is...

`items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"<repositoryname>"}, "name":{"$eq" : "<artifactoryItemName>"}}) .sort({"$desc" : ["created"]})`

The descending sort order is specified with `$desc` sort operator on the timestamp field `created`.

You can also limit the number of results returned by adding an extra `limit` to the above query...

`items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"<repositoryname>"}, "name":{"$eq" : "<artifactoryItemName>"}}) .sort({"$desc" : ["created"]}).limit(10)`

The AQL needs to be submitted at `/artifactory/api/search/aql`.
The same can be done via REST API as well with a POST request. The content should be posted not as a JSON but directly in the way query is specified as-is as text. The header for content type is `Content-Type:text/plain`. You can use the Basic authentication or other supported authentication methods.

There are a ton of things you can do with AQL. The syntax can look a bit confusing to begin with.